# Creating a project without projection/simple Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgsmapcanvas

I want to draw a schematic process diagram in QGIS (yes, I really want, because I can document my data in the table) but it seems impossible to create a CRS that is simple Cartesian (x,y). Anyone can give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any *projected* CRS you like, they are all simple Cartesian grids, but don't use a geographic (lat/lon) CRS. You could use EPSG:27700 for example.

Comment: my problem is, there ar all not realy northing, meaning, that the grid ist not exact perpendicular to the canvas. lets see if i can upload a image . .

Comment: as you can see in the image, the cartesian grid (EPSG 3857 in this case) is not perpendicular to the canvas and that ist disturbing

Comment: sorry, you are right, i had made my layer in EPSG 32720 an was showing in 3857. that was the problem!

Answer (score 8):

If you go to project properties, CRS tab you can turn on the "no projection" option. This should achieve what you're after.